# force Django to use new connection every time

Tags: python, django

I'm using the default database setting for Django, and `conn_max_age` is not set.   Hence, it must be taking 0 as default.

I would like to force Django to use new connection for each request.   How do I force Django to use a new connection on every request?

Comment: WIth 0 as default Django it's already using a connection for every request https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#conn-max-age what do you mean?

Comment: Django will create new connection for each new request and then close.

Comment: What if 2 request comes one after another will the second request will use same which is still running ?

Comment: @MukeshYadav simply put, no. Each python process has its own connection and can serve 1 request at a time. So either the other request will be processed by another process of your or will be processed at the same process, both with different connections.